# How to change component size in expressSCH?

Tags: pcb-design

I have a sketch with too small AND gates and too small capacitors etc.
Is there a way to enlarge them?

When I right-click the component it lets me change only the text size....

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't scale components of schematic images in ExpressSCH relative to grid. What you do is to create your own components of the size and shape you wish. For instructions how to do custom schematic components, see their [help article](https://www.expresspcb.com/guide-to-making-schematic-components-for-expresssch/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies with the other parts.

The capacitors, resistors, and ground symbols are from ExpressPCB itself.  The other components are not standard symbols.

These non-standard symbols were drawn wrong, so that they are too large in comparison to the symbols from the ExpressPCB standad library.

To be honest, those other "symbols" don't even look like proper parts.  Just from the look of them, I want to say they were drawn using some drawing primitives (boxes, text, lines) directly in the schematic rather than having been created as schematic symbols.

I've never used ExpessPCB, so I could be wrong.  But it really looks that way. There should be simple black dots where the wires connect to the parts.  For the original symbols, you do see the dots.  Everywhere else, there are gray squares.  That seems to say to me that there are no electrical connections on those junctions.

The capacitor to the left of the dialog is a good example of a correct connection.  The capacitor and the ground symbol below it are symbols from the library.  They are connected, and there's a proper dot at the junction.

Pin 4 of whatever is covered by the dialog is a good example of something that looks really wrong.  The pin itself is outside of the box.  The wire it is connected to doesn't have a dot, it is a gray square.

The "IR Led" and the switches should have symbols in the standard library.  These should represent the function rather than being detailless boxes.